# Edit a .PHP file using PHP

Tags: php

I have example language file en.php

```
<?php

$language = array(
    "language_code" => "en",
    "language_name" => "English",


);
```

These language files replace replace certain things in template files to support multi-language.

Is there a way to add stuff into the array using PHP?
So I do something in the settings, e.g. add a new language value and the PHP adds this to the file en.php and saves it.

I wonder if this is possible because it can be quite complicated I guess. If it is possible, a slight suggestion to do so would be appreciated. I don't have much experience editing files in php.

If it would be better, I could change the language format to XML if that makes it easier.

Thanks

Comment: and yes XML is defiantly easier and faster and makes more sense to use.

Comment: Then the question would be How would I edit XML file?

Comment: and why don't you edit `en.php` itself?

Comment: Because there are more than one en.php language files, and I am a lazy administrator. Also, the PHP itself adds new language values when a new module is added to site.

Comment: @mkram0: then you will go and learn how to edit XML from web articles and books if you have. feel free to come back and ask if you got stack some any where.

Comment: Also there is a high chance the your application uses database, why not add another table for languages ?

Comment: It does use database, but storing languages in some table would be impossible and slow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of storing data in php code (or XML), use [JSON](http://php.net/var_export). Load the data with:

```
$json = file_get_contents('en.json');
if ($json === false) throw new Exception('Cannot read file!');
$language = json_decode($json, true); // true tells json_decode to export as array ;)
```

and store it with:

```
$json = json_encode($language);
if (file_put_contents('en.json', $json) === false) {
  throw new Exception('Can not store language');
}
```

If you really insist on storing your data as a php program, use the [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) function:

```
$phpCode = "<?php\n\n" . '$language = ' . var_export($language, true) . ';';
if (file_put_contents('en.php', $phpCode) === false) {
    throw new Exception('Can not store language');
}
```

There's no need to use XML, since it would be slower and more complicated than JSON. Also, you should generally not store translations in a (relational) database, since the round trip time and repeated query parsing and evaluation are prone to slow down your application.

Comment: this is excelent and far easy. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you introduce an xml file (or a database) where you store the possible languages and use that instead of the array you are describing?

Comment: what about the performance of this way when you load 20 or more values from DB